# Continue capture after break with pcap.net

Tags: capture, pcap.net, communicator

I am working with pcap.net.

I have a communicator that recieves packets.
At some point I call the Break() function to stop the capture.
after I stopped the capture, I want to continue the capture at some point..

I tried using the RecievePackets(HandlePacket, 0) again, but my GUI froze..
my code:

```
private void StartCapture()
{
    _Communicator.RecievePackets(HandlePacket, 0);
}

private void StopCapture()
{
    _Communicator.Break();
}
```

any help??
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the code of your GUI, but ReceivePackets() is a blocking call and will hold your thread.

If you're doing this inside the GUI thread, it will freeze your GUI. You should do it in a different thread.

Comment: I am not doing this from my GUI thread. the first time I start capture it works. then I break the capture. and after this. I try the _Communicator.RecievePackets(HandlePacket, 0) again and it freezes the GUI and everything. all of this is done not from the GUI thread.. any help??

Comment: I suggest replacing the call to ReceivePackets() with a different infinite loop. That will allow you to debug this regardless of Pcap.Net functionality.